# Mysql LEFT JOIN table filter original table properly

Tags: php, mysql, database

So i have following tables. As you can see it all works amazing.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e19e5/1

My issue is that i'd like to be able to filter by user_id on the punch_clock table.

When i add AND user_id = 3; to the end of the sql statement it doesn't show the empty results..

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join with where turns into inner join and will try to return data where everything matched, you may need to use the condition on the joining part as

```
SELECT *
FROM calendar_table AS cal
LEFT JOIN punch_clock AS puc
  ON (cal.dt = DATE(puc.punch_time))
  and puc.user_id = 3
WHERE TRUE
  AND cal.week_num = 22
  AND cal.y = 2015;
```